# Finding all two column duplicates in SQL table where later value of third column is greater than earlier value

Tags: sql, sqlite

Fairly new to SQL and it would be great to have a slicker take on this problem.

Here's an example table:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2011-01-22 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 2011-01-27 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 2011-01-20 |
| 3 | 8 | 4 | 2011-01-12 |
| 3 | 8 | 2 | 2011-01-30 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 2011-01-09 |
| 5 | 3 | 3 | 2011-01-27 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 | 2011-01-22 |

and I'd like to return all distinct col1, col2 values where

- The col1 and col2 values are the same (duplicated)
  and
- The latest col3 value is greater than the earliest one

In this case, the result should be

| col1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

I can do

```
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

to get the duplicate col1, col2 tuples but from there my solution just gets ugly, using multiple nested subqueries and sometimes repeating the same subquery.

What's a clean way to do this? It's in SQLite.

Comment: If there are 3 rows with same col1/col2 combination, and the third ones col3 is larger then the first one's, but smaller than the second row's col3?

Comment: Good point, I should have said "latest" and "earliest" instead of "later" and "earlier" -- I've edited to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER` here with pivoting logic:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2
                           ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT col1, col2
FROM cte
GROUP BY col1, col2
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN col3 END) >
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN col3 END);
```

### Demo

This approach is very close to what you are currently doing.  The only addition is a `HAVING` clause which compares the more recent `col3` value against the older one.  Note that this answer assumes that your "duplicates" would only be occurring as pairs, and not triplets, etc.

**Edit:**

If, for some reason, you really can't use window functions, e.g. because you are using a really old version of SQLite, we can still use roughly the above approach with a join:

```sql
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT col1, col2, MIN(date) AS min_date, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY col1, col2
) t2
    ON t2.col1 = t1.col1 AND t2.col2 = t1.col2
GROUP BY t1.col1, t1.col2
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.date = t2.max_date THEN col3 END) >
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.date = t2.min_date THEN col3 END);
```

### Demo

Comment: I suspected a window function would be useful. This came up in the context of a course that didn't discuss these -- any thoughts on a clean solution without window functions? Thanks for the reminder about ```WITH``` clause for cutting down on subquery repeats.

Comment: @rmwenzel Sure, I have updated with an alternative which does not use window functions.  By the way, you requirement is not so far out there, as earlier versions of SQLite did not have full support for window functions.

Comment: A clean alternative @Tim. Why do we need to pass the `CASE` statements in the `HAVING` clause to the `MAX` function? It seems unnecessary since we're just trying to compare col3 values for min and max dates. I tried removing them in the demo and ended up getting a `NULL` value for the max date case statement, but don't understand why. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2,
         FIRST_VALUE(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY date) earlier_col3,
         FIRST_VALUE(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY date DESC) latest_col3
  FROM tablename
)
WHERE latest_col3 > earlier_col3
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7e273576e428301cbab1da67404c56e4).
Results:

```
> col1 | col2
> ---: | ---:
>    1 |    1
```

Comment: I suspected a window function would be useful. This came up in the context of a course that didn't discuss these -- any thoughts on a clean solution without window functions?

Comment: @rmwenzel what do you mean by *clean* solution? Window functions are standard SQL since 2003 and SQLite supports them since version 3.25.0 (2018-09-15):https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html

Comment: thanks @forpas I recognize that window functions are standard, and your solution definitely satisfies my understanding of "clean". But as my comment indicated, I was working on this problem in a course that hadn't taught window functions, so I was curious about a solution without them. I had my own solution without window functions but it wasn't very "clean". In this case, by clean I mean I mean minimal code repetition and nesting.